# Changing the units in a contour plot from vis.gam in mgcv

Tags: r, graphics, mgcv

I'm fitting a model using the log of a variable, and I'd like to present my results in terms of that variable transformed.  Here is a simple example:

```
library(mgcv)
N = seq(from=1,to=10,by=.01)
a = N^2
b = 1/N
y = log(a*b*runif(length(N)))
mod = gam(y~te(a,b))
vis.gam(mod, plot.type="contour")
```

I'd like to produce the same graph, but based on `exp(y)` instead of `y`.

Any ideas on how to do this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As often happens, the solution occurred to me immediately after asking the question.

Just type `vis.gam` and get the function.  Copy/paste it into the script file.  It is a long function.  Somewhere midway:

```
fv <- predict.gam(x, newdata = newd, se.fit = TRUE, type = type)
fv$fit = exp(fv$fit)   #INSERT THIS LINE HERE WITH WHATEVER FUNCTION YOU WANT TO MODIFY THE FITTED VALUES BY
z <- fv$fit
```

Then change the function name to "mod.vis.gam" or something, and use it like any function.   Works great.  Note that SE's aren't affected.